# Difference between the degree of dependence, and structure of dependence?

Tags: correlation, independence, copula

- Correlation measures the **degree of dependence** between two variables,
  while the
- copula function defines the degree of dependence as well as their  **structure
  of dependence**.

How does the concept of dependence structure differ from that of degree of dependence? Is it to say that correlation treats any sort of co-movement in any direction linear and equally (static and non-invariant to the direction/location of change), whereas the dependence structure recognizes both linear and non-linear co-movement being *dynamically* different, for example, in the lower and upper tails vs centralized changes?

Comment: Correlation only measures degree of linear dependence, not degree of dependence in general. What do you mean by *movement* and *dynamic* in the context of correlation and copulas? We have a fixed joint distribution (no movement, no dynamics), do we not?

Comment: How should dependence structure be defined then

Comment: What do you mean by movement and dynamic in the context of correlation and copulas? We have a fixed joint distribution (no movement, no dynamics), do we not?

Comment: alright dynamics is the wrong term then. what I'm trying to describe are the locations on the copula density surface, where the corners (tails) are a divergence from the rest of the structure of the surface since they curl up or down. How should I rephrase the question